# Applying for higher position, although I never did the work before

Tags: resume, new-job, cover-letter

I want to apply for fiber optic planner position, although ever just being a technician.

I believe I would be able to do the work. I have no formal education to confirm this. I would I communicate this in a resume and application letter to really get consider for the position.

What would be the best way to put this in a resume and letter?

Comment: Oops. How do I put this in a resume and letter?

Comment: After trying to prepare a CV and cover letter, I found that I lack a few key skills. Nothing a short course won't fix but still. Thanks for all the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are already working at the company. If so, instead of going through HR for the job and an application, find a sponsor in that department that will let you apprentice with him. Make yourself smart and likable, let your current boss know you think you can *create more value for the company* this way. Set goals that you want to meet for the company and make it clear you intend to *exceed those goals*.

Accept that it may take a few months of moonlighting, but maybe it's less months and cost than if you went to school and learn it formally. You may also not get paid much more because you will probably be paid what you are making now and might only get recognized far later.

You could also ask your manager about creating a reimbursement agreement. You pay for the costs of a formal certificate program up front, but the company agrees to reimburse you when you pass the courses with some agreed upon grades. In this manner, their risk of spending a lot of money on something you aren't serious about is mitigated. Companies love to hire from within because internal people already know the culture and there are no recruiter fees. If you can prove you are the best bet for the next open role and they have some investment in you, of course you will get hired for the job!

Comment: My current employers Is a mom and pop shop. There is no room for growth. They aren't very positive people. But I do have someone I can get into contact with. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Good luck! Life is a big experiment... :D

Answer (score 5):

This is a specialised field, your best bet is to get formally qualified. It's normally a requirement for these positions and the work is complex and covers many areas from fieldwork to design.

If you are a technician who has been involved in fibre projects then getting qualified is the next logical step. But it's a big leap from basic technician to fibre planner, there's a whole bunch more skills you need. Formal qualification proves you have them.

Still, there is nothing to stop you applying for any job, and if you have relevant experience you may get lucky. List any experience you have that you feel is helpful, particularly network design and build. And anything to do with fibre that you have been involved with.

Answer (score 3):

While lack of formal education in the field might not be a deal breaker (e.g. I studied education and I implement Web Analytics Systems for a living) lack of relevant experience probably is.

"I believe" is not going to convince anybody. You must be able to make a case that your previous work has prepared you for the challenges of the higher position. I frankly have no idea what being a "fiber optic planner" entails in its job description, but typically higher paying jobs involve skills beyond the technology (being able to talk to and negotiate with clients, managerial skills etc.), so you need to be sure you are in some way prepared for that.

Else you'd have to take the long way and somehow aquire the necessary skill set (night school, online studies etc.) and then try again to apply.

Comment: So basically add acquired skills with each project done. If I don't have the skill or can't get it through experience, go and study it. Right?

Comment: At least this is how it worked for me, yes.

Comment: Thanks. Time to get to work then, to make sure I can do the job.

Comment: While I appreciate the reputation you should not accept answers after only 20 minutes. There might be more and betters answers to come.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an opportunity to work at a position is the real education. You may try to get additional skills through other means but it should not stop you from applying now. You should represent yourself as accurately as possible but as close to the desired skill set as you can on your resume. I do not know the details of your current job but I am sure there would have been some opportunities where you had to do some activities from your desired role. (like planning layout or team leading, etc.). Think hard and bring out such events on your resume.

In your cover letter you can express your passion more emphatically as why you want to do this job and why you think you can handle it even without formal education on this. Like you can take the points in the job description one by one and express in your letter how either you have already done it or you think you can do it based on certain demonstrable evidences from other aspects of your life. (Soft skills like leadership or planning).